# FIFO block program until other process read

Tags: c++, mkfifo

I am using a FIFO file, created as `mkfifo myFIFO` on Linux terminal, in a C++ code bellow:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
     FILE* fp = fopen("/tmp/myFIFO", "w");
     fprintf(fp, "Hello, world!\n");
     fclose(fp);
     cout << "!!!Hello World!!!" << endl; // prints !!!Hello World!!!
     return 0;
 }
```

The program stays blocked until other process read `myFIFO`. How to avoid this? (I want that this peace of code stay processing and writing in the FIFO not carrying about the other process read. Until the FIFO be full, when, if possible, I may discard the oldest messages).

Comment: I created by terminal `mkfifo myFIFO`. I will edit the content to clarify.

Comment: Note that a fifo is generally implemented as a fixed size (typically 4k on \*nix) IO device.  If you want to write all data to the device *before* the other process begins to read it then I don't think a fifo is what you want.

Comment: There is no problem about this. My data will be now longer than 512B, so I could write 8 times before problems (considering 4k). My issue is that I couldn't do a main loop software that not stay waiting for the other side to read the FIFO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way that I found was, using the `O_NONBLOCK` option, write in the file/pipe the content of a internal queue of the software. So the buffer is created by the writer software and the pipe file have the function only of message channel.

Answer (score 2):

You need to open your FIFO in a non-blocking mode. To do so, use [`::open`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/open) instead of `fopen`, and do specify the `O_NONBLOCK` option.

You will also need to use [`::write`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/write) instead of `fprintf`.

Comment: For additional kudos, you might want to give an example ;)

Comment: I did so
`
int file_descr = open(FILE_FIFO, O_WRONLY | O_NONBLOCK);
    if (file_descr < 0)
    {
        printf("open fifo error: %d\n", file_descr);
        return -1;
    }
    write(file_descr, "Hello, world!\n", 14);
   close(file_descr);
`
But my program doesn't write in the fifo. Just I the other process is already hearing.

Comment: I want to create a file FIFO that works like a device (having a buffer). So the main software write and not wait to be read, I don't want to create a physical file because device and FIFO already have flush().

Comment: So, does the writing process need to be able to exit *before* the reader has read all of the data?  Or should it wait until all data has been read?

Comment: It could wait, this is not a problem for the application intended.